# Tensorflow C API: SessionRun batch size (how to properly set)

Tags: c, api, tensorflow

I am struggling to find the correct way to properly set the batch size for a SessionRun call in the C API.
What I am trying to do is passing multiple images in a single SessionRun to a CNN (VGG16).
I am wondering which is the correct way to do so and to retrieve the appropriate correlated output values.
I have also come to believe that a single SessionRun call can only accept a single image as an input, so a proper batched input could only be achieved by having multiple SessionRun calls (for an example inside a "for" loop) with a single image each. Am I correct? Is there not a way to batch multiple images inside a single SessionRun call for a single-input CNN?

I have searched thoroughly Tensorflow C API documentation but I could not find any evidence of a proper indication on how to do it.

I have tried these pseudo-code: (calling these code SISO = Single Input Single Output, and MIMO = Multiple Input Multiple Output, the input is batch_size * 50 * 50 * 3, in SISO batch_size = 1, in MIMO batch_size = 3; remember that I am using VGG16 graph)

SISO:

```
loadGraph()
TF_NewSession()
TF_AllocateTensor( 1 * 50 * 50 * 3)
// copy data into tensor
num_bytes = rows() * cols() * channels() * sizeof(float);
memcpy(tensor_data, img_data, num_bytes)
TF_SessionRun()
data = static_cast<float*>(TF_TensorData(output_tensor));
// data[0] = frame number
// data[1] = probabily of prediction
out = (data[1] > 0.5f) ? true : false;
```

for SISO, I have always the right output.

MIMO:

```
loadGraph()
TF_NewSession()
TF_AllocateTensor( 3 * 50 * 50 * 3)
// copy data into tensor
num_bytes = rows() * cols() * channels() * sizeof(float);
offset = 0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    memcpy(tensor_data + offset, imgs_data[i], num_bytes);
    offset += num_bytes;
}
TF_SessionRun()
data = static_cast<float*>(TF_TensorData(output_tensor));
offset = 0;
num_bytes = 2 * sizeof(float);
// data[i] = frame number
// data[i+1] = probabily of prediction
for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    out[i] = (*(data + offset + 1) > 0.5f) ? true : false;
    offset += num_bytes;
}
```

for MIMO, only the first classification output value is right, the other ones are random numbers.

what is wrong with this code?